# How to set focus of my cursor from exit event of one textbox to another textbox

Tags: vba, excel

I have a userform with two textboxes `BPName2` and `SPName2`.  After the `If found=true then exit for` statement in below code. I would like to move to the 2nd textbox. But, having trouble doing so. Anyone have an idea on how to do this?

```
Private Sub txt_BPName2_Exit(ByVal Cancel As ReturnBoolean)

Dim Row As Integer
  Row = ActiveCell.Row
  Dim c As Range
  Dim found As Boolean


  found = False
    For Each c In Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
        If c.Value = txt_BPName2 Then MsgBox "Cell " & c.Address & " Base Product Found."
        If c.Value = txt_BPName2 Then found = True
    If found = True Then Exit For

    Next

    If found = False Then
         'Cells(Row, 1).Value = txt_BPName2.Text
         MsgBox ("Base Product not found")
         'ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
         Add_Inventory_SP.Hide
    End If

    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do after that line of code?

Comment: Comment out the line with `MsgBox`. Does that do what you want?

Comment: Like `NextTextBoxName.SetFocus`? Also your code can be modified to be more efficient.

Comment: Is `SPName2` the next control in the tab order? If so, then just don't set `Cancel = True` for that circumstance. If not, you're likely fighting a losing battle since any `SetFocus` command will be followed by the buffered tab that raised the exit event.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things

1. Whenever you are working with Excel Rows, please use `Long` instead of `Integer`. Post Excel 2007, the number of rows have gone up to 1048576 which an Integer cannot handle
2. You do not need a Boolean Variable
3. Fully qualify your objects. Avoid using `Activecell`. You may want to see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)
4. Avoid using reserved words as variable names. `Row` is  reserved word.

Is this what you are trying? (**Untested**)

```
Private Sub txt_BPName2_Exit(ByVal Cancel As ReturnBoolean)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim c As Range, rng As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<~~ Change as applicable

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Set rng = .Range("A2:A" & lRow)
    End With

    For Each c In rng
        If c.Value = txt_BPName2 Then
            MsgBox "Cell " & c.Address & " Base Product Found."

            SPName2.SetFocus
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next

    MsgBox ("Base Product not found")
    Add_Inventory_SP.Hide
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

**Note**: A more efficient approach in lieu of looping and searching would be to use `.Find` or `Application.Worksheetfunction.CountIf` to search for the name in the range. If you are interested in `.Find` then you can see [This](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/)

Comment: @ Siddharth Rout- Thanks ! Your approach is much better.